# How to assing the for loop result into a vector with R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

First time here hehe. I know that probably my question is a dumb one but I couldn't find the answer with the others questions I've looked into.

I'm trying to convert a string vector (from a larger data frame) which indicates the bands preferences into "1" and "0", being 1 for a specific band and 0 for all others. However, my code is working fine when I use print(), without assigning the results. When I try to use return() or another assignment mode, It comes with an error or only one value. Here is my code:

```
 for(x in ){
  if('Pb&C' %in% x){
print(1)} else{
print(0)}
}
}
```

How can I get the results into a vector?

I've tried these, but all with errors:

```
for (x in rejeicao) {
     if ('Pb&C' %in% x) {
   a <- return(1)
 }  else{
  a <- return(0)
}
}

a
```

and also:

```
for (x in rejeicao) {
     if ('Pb&C' %in% x) {
   a[x,] <- return(1)
 }  else{
  a[x,] <- return(0)
}
}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is a vectorized language, so you simply need to assign the result of the test to the desired variable.

This code will result in a TRUE/FALSE value.

```
a <- rejeicao == 'Pb&C'
```

To convert to 0/1, we use the fact that TRUE becomes 1 and FALSE becomes 0 when used in a mathematical expression.

```
a <- (rejeicao == 'Pb&C')*1
```

You'll want to learn more about the other keywords you tried using, namely, `%in%` and `return`, as I don't think they're doing what you think they are. But StackOverflow is a question/answer site where it's important to ask specific questions and answer them specifically, not a mailing list, so those details aren't appropriate to include here.

Comment: Using `as.numeric(rejeicao)` can also be done to convert to 0/1.